# npm install @david.kucsai/react-pdf-table ERRROR

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, pdf

estoy queriendo instalar lo siguiente en mi React APP : npm install @david.kucsai/react-pdf-table , a la hora de dar enter, me arroja el siguiente error :

```
En línea: 1 Carácter: 13
+ npm install @david.kucsai/react-pdf-table
+             ~~~~~~
El operador de expansión '@' no se puede usar para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión. '@david' solamente se puede usar 
como argumento para un comando. Para hacer referencia a variables en una expresión, use '$david'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

Alguno sabe como resolverlo o que puede ser? Tengo Windows 10 Home.. Desde ya muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Espero que lo hayas resuelto, pero al parecer el problema es que a npm (en Windono le parece bien la sintaxis `@algo.`, lo que si podria funcionar es sin el `.` ya que hay paquetes que tienen distintas funcionalidades según la versión del autor.

Como lo detalla el autor en la descripcion del paquete en github, en windows hay que escapar el nombre del paquete:

```
 npm install "@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table"
```

Se ve que tuvo varios problemas con eso